# enqueue script on custom post type archive page

Tags: customization, wp-enqueue-script

How do I enqueue a script on the header if the user is on an archive page of a custom post type? The custom post type is called `limitedrun` and the page is called `archive-limitedrun.php`.

I tried this and got no response:

```
function opby_theme() {
wp_register_script('responsive-img', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/responsive-img.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('responsive-img');
wp_enqueue_style( 'opby', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.co/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100|Bitter');
wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
if (is_singular('limitedrun') ) {
wp_register_style('ltd-run-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,500');
wp_enqueue_style( 'ltd-run-font');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'opby_theme' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save your time and server load by not using `wp_register_script` and `wp_register_style` when you don't need them definitely. `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` do the same job themselves when not involving excessive functions.

Here is easier and more readable code up to date with the accepted answer by @vancoder:

```
<?php
function opby_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'responsive-img',
         get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/responsive-img.min.js',
         array('jquery')
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'opby',
        get_stylesheet_uri()
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'googleFonts',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.co/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100|Bitter'
    );

    if ( is_post_type_archive('limitedrun') ) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'ltd-run-font',
            'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,500'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'opby_theme' );
```

Answer (score 3):

`is_singular` doesn't handle archives.

Try

```
is_post_type_archive( 'limitedrun' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `template_redirect` action hook for exactly that.

This hook is the point where WordPress knows which templates the user is viewing and gets fired just before the template files are loaded.

Here is an example, where a stylesheet is only loaded for the post archive:

`

```
// Call the hook and register your function
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'register_styles_for_post_archive' );

// Call your function which enqueues the stylesheet only for the post archive
function register_styles_for_post_archive() {

// put in your post type as a parameter or leave empty for the actual post type
    if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_types ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('your-custom-stylesheet-name', 'your-css-file.css', false, 01, 'screen');

    }
}
```

`